# For the few lines of below python code snippet, need explanation.

Tags: python, string, eval, string-formatting

Below python code are used for perform operation like append,sort,print on the list`L`.I was analyzing the code, but unable to understand few lines in the code.

```
 l = []#declare the list
 choices = {"0": "", "1": "{}()", "2": "{}({})", "3": "{}({}, {})"}#dicationary declaration
 for _ in range(int(raw_input())):  #prompt for user input and iterate 
        cmds = raw_input().split(" ")   #get the operation that needs to be performed on the list
        choice = str(len(cmds))   #get the length
        if cmds[0] == "print": print l   #print the list
        elif choice in choices: eval("l." + choices[choice].format(*cmds))
```

Dictionary declaration,`choices = {"0": "", "1": "{}()", "2": "{}({})", "3": "{}({}, {})"}`have  brackets and parenthesis, I am unable to understand its significance. The last line`elif choice in choices: eval("l." + choices[choice].format(*cmds))` seems to be mysterious because of

1. `eval` function which is be used to execute the Python code.
2. string function `format` which seems to be obscure with the
   addition of symbols `*`.

Input are in the below format

```
insert 0 6
print 
remove 6
append 9
```

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Comment: `eval` is generally unsafe to use. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @roganjosh got it from hackerank

Comment: @Chris I don't have clear understanding about the code, as far my understanding it is executing some operation on list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really ugly code. `insert 0 6` is invalid as the *first* input; first you must state how many times you want to use this monstrosity e.g. `1`.

Then:

1. The input `insert 0 6` has three parameters in it. `cmds = raw_input.split(" ")` and `choice = str(len(cmds))` then works out that you passed three (`3`) parameters to the code.
2. The number `3` is then used to give back the appropriate formatting string from `choices = {"0": "", "1": "{}()", "2": "{}({})", "3": "{}({}, {})"}`. In this case; `"{}({}, {})"`
3. We didn't ask for a `print`, we asked for `insert`, so `if cmds[0] == "print": print l` is `False` and we skip it.
4. This means we then have to evaluate `elif choice in choices: eval("l." + choices[choice].format(*cmds))`. Well, we already know from point (2) that `choice == 3` corresponds to `"{}({}, {})"`. The `(*cmds))` is for tuple unpacking... it unpacks `(input, 0, 6)` into the string at the curly braces, giving `"insert(0, 6)"`.
5. We then concatenate the string at the end of (4) to give "l.insert(0, 6)" as a string. That is then passed to `eval` and executed.

Answer (score 1):

This function allows the user to input methods that work on a list as raw input. It then creates a string with that is a valid line of python code and evaluates it on the list.

The `choices` dictionary contains the format strings that are used to construct the line that will be evaluated. The brackets `{}` will be substituted by items from the input list in the `.format` call. The parenthesis `()` are the parenthesis used to make it a proper function call in python.

If you replace the `eval` with `print` you will see exactly what the command looks like after the substitutions.

Also note, this code only works for Python 2, for Python 3 you need to use:

```
l = []#declare the list
choices = {"0": "", "1": "{}()", "2": "{}({})", "3": "{}({}, {})"}#dicationary declaration
for _ in range(int(input())):  #prompt for user input and iterate 
    cmds = input().split(" ")   #get the operation that needs to be performed on the list
    choice = str(len(cmds))   #get the length
    if cmds[0] == "print": print(l)   #print the list
    elif choice in choices: eval("l." + choices[choice].format(*cmds))
```

Comment: "the parenthesis used to make it a proper function call in python" I missed that in my answer and meant to address it. +1.